# Reduce number of Tomcat's Daemon Threads

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I'm using Tomcat 5.5 with Eclipse and at every startup the Tomcat spawns about 15 to 20 Daemon threads. It's usefull if you want to handle several requests "at once".
This is superficial on my development server and wastes ressources.

How can I reduce this number of Daemon threads?

Comment: 20 threads in java is not wasting anything, they're very lightweight and take up no resource when they're idle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, aren't you a bit exaggerating on this? *"Wastes resources"* with only 15-20 threads? Or is it just that they *annoy* you somehow? What's the exact problem you have with this?

At any way, best what you can do is to take a look in the [HTTP connector configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html). There in you have attributes like `acceptCount`, `maxSpareThreads` and `maxThreads` with which you can play.

Comment: Yes, I'm exaggerating. :) I'm just curious how to change it.

Comment: BalusC response helped, with minSpareThreads. But it still show many threads, even with minSpareThreads=1:
one thread per port,per core. Plus main,TP and port monitor. The real question here is how to filter threads, so that one only see what is relevant for the debugging session.